# Найти элем в первом словаре сравнить с вторым если совпадает из второго достать количеств и цену

Tags: python, list, циклы, словари

В базе данных магазина мебели вся необходимая информация по товарам делится на два словаря: первый отвечает за коды товаров, второй - за списки количества разнообразных товаров на складе:

```
goods = {

    'Лампа': '12345',

    'Стол': '23456',

    'Диван': '34567',

    'Стул': '45678',

}

store = {

    '12345': [

        {'quantity': 27, 'price': 42},

    ],

    '23456': [

        {'quantity': 22, 'price': 510},

        {'quantity': 32, 'price': 520},

    ],

    '34567': [

        {'quantity': 2, 'price': 1200},

        {'quantity': 1, 'price': 1150},

    ],

    '45678': [

        {'quantity': 50, 'price': 100},

        {'quantity': 12, 'price': 95},

        {'quantity': 43, 'price': 97},

    ],

}
```

Каждая запись второго словаря отображает сколько и по какой цене закупалось товаров (цена указана за 1 шт.)

Напишите программу, которая рассчитывает на какую сумму лежит каждого товара на складе и выводит эту информацию на экран.

В общем решение у меня такое, но оно неверное т.к сумма будет не верной если количество вложенных словарей больше 1

```
def summ_product(dic_goods, dic_store):
    summ1 = 0
    full_price = 0
    for key_goods, elem_goods in dic_goods.items():
        for k in dic_store.keys():
            if elem_goods == k:
                for i in dic_store[k]:
                    for key, elem in i.items():
                        if key == 'quantity':
                            summ1 += elem
                        if key == 'price':
                            full_price = elem * summ1
        print('{key_goods} - {quantity} шт, стоимость 
            {priceруб.'.format(key_goods=key_goods,quantity=summ1,price=full_price))
        summ1 = 0
        full_price = 0
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой вариант:

```
code_sum = {}
for code in store: # перебираем все коды товаров
    s = 0
    for x in store[code]: # перебираем вложенные словари для каждого товара
        s += x['quantity']*x['price'] # суммируем стоимости
    code_sum[code] = s
good_sum = {}
for name, code in goods.items():
    good_sum[name] = code_sum[code]
```

Но можно сделать в одну строку:

```
good_sum = {name: sum(x["quantity"] * x["price"] for x in store[code]) for name, code in goods.items()}
```

Comment: Спасибо! разобрался